# How to export qr_code img to disk?

Tags: python-3.x, save, qr-code

I generate a qr code image from an url using the python package [qrcode](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/):

```
url='www.google.com'
qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1,
                   error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
                   box_size=10,
                   border=4)

qr.add_data(url)
qr.make(fit=True)
img = qr.make_image()
return img
```

How do I save the img to the disk at a certain path ?

I tried:

```
image_file = open(path_qr_code, 'w')
image_file.write(img)
image_file.close
```

but I get:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not PilImage

Comment: Hint: "Not PIL Image", then you can search "how to save an PIL Image to disk".

Comment: Then I found this https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not PilImage

This indicates that `img` has type `PilImage`, then you can use the way [saving a `PilImage`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) to save it. For example,

```
img.save(path_qr_code)
```